# Maximum number of breakpoints in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, breakpoints, google-chrome-devtools

Does anyone know what the limit is on the maximum number of breakpoints that can be set with Google Chrome's Web Inspector? Thanks.

Comment: Is it for general knowledge, or have you encountered a problem already?

Comment: I haven't encountered a problem yet, but want to be sure that it'll be able to handle several thousand breakpoints in the future.

Comment: Several thousand?! Why would you need that many breakpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of breakpoints is only limited by your hardware resources (memory for storing them and CPU for quickly handling this lot of DOM elements.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no explicit limit for the number of breakpoints. However you should expect that some algorithms are not well optimized for a large number of breakpoints, e.g. some internal searches may well be O(n).