# Maximum number of breakpoints with puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, breakpoints, chrome-devtools-protocol

Does anyone know what the limit is on the maximum number of breakpoints that can be set with Puppeteer? I will collect all stacktraces when debugger is hit these breakpoints with Debugger.paused event.

Answer (score 0):

It can be said that it is only related with hardware resources as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224612/11527186.